# SQLite CASE LIKE returning NULL

Tags: sqlite, case, sql-like

I'm trying to run a query to check for a substring, and when that substring exists I want the query to return a value of my choosing.

I run SELECT CASE WHEN COLUMNNAME LIKE '%"cashtag":null%' THEN 'NO CASH TAG' END COLUMNNAME FROM TABLENAME

I've run this same command with different variables and it worked fine. But with it written this way to look for "cashtag":null I get return values of NULL in my query result.

I've provided an image of what one of my cells in COLUMNAME looks like:
[image]

SO for instance, for this particular cell, I expect to get a return of NO CASH TAG in my query result. But it returns NULL. Not sure what it is about this particular "cashtag":null value that is throwing things off. As I stated, I have used other values with a similar format with the CASE WHEN LIKE functions and they worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case I can think of that this may happen is if `COLUMNAME` contains NUL character (ASCII code `0`) before the substring `'"cashtag":null'`.
If this happens, SQLite's `LIKE` operator can't locate the substring after the *NUL character*.
For example:

```
SELECT 'abc' || char(0) || 'def' LIKE '%e%'
```

returns `0` (`FALSE`).
But:

```
SELECT 'abc' || char(0) || 'def' LIKE '%a%'
```

returns `1` (`TRUE`).

You can check for *NUL characters* with:

```
SELECT INSTR(COLUMNNAME, char(0)) [position of NUL char]
FROM TABLENAME
```

In any case, use `INSTR()` instead of `LIKE` which will work even with *NUL characters*:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN INSTR(COLUMNNAME, '"cashtag":null') THEN 'NO CASH TAG' END COLUMNNAME 
FROM TABLENAME
```

The only difference here is that `LIKE` is by default case insensitive but `INSTR()` case sensitive.
So `INSTR(COLUMNNAME, '"cashtag":null')` will not find `'"Cashtag":NULL'`.
If you need case insensitive search use `UPPER()` function also:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN INSTR(UPPER(COLUMNNAME), UPPER('"cashtag":null')) THEN 'NO CASH TAG' END COLUMNNAME 
FROM TABLENAME
```

Now the problem is that `UPPER()` works only for the  ASCII characters of the string and not UNICODE characters beyond the ASCII range.

Comment: I didn't know that about the NUL character with LIKE operators. Makes way more sense now. The INSTR() command worked perfect. Thanks again for your help!